# How can I get the Information in search bar on click or Enter. Then paste it to another input on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using this form.

```
          <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
           </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I want to take the "input" when the Go! button is pushed, or the user hits <enter> on the keyboard. I want to take that input and put it on another page

```
  Search: <input ng-model="query">
```

I am trying to learn how to use Jquery.

```
<script>
$( "#id" ).click(function() 
{
  "I don't know what to do here"
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are describing basic HTML form submission. You should submit the form in the normal way to support non-JavaScript users. If you wish to do something with JavaScript, you can still use `$('.navbar-form').submit(function(event){ your_code_here  });` Include `event.preventDefault()` in your code if you don't want to load the submit page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say if you wanna take it to a page, `search?query=TheSearchText`, you can use `location.href`:

```
$( "#id" ).click(function () {
  location.href='search?query=' + $('[ng-model="query"]').val();
});
```

In better words, please give an `id` to the search text:

```
<input ng-model="query" id="query" />
```

```
$( "#id" ).click(function () {
  location.href='search?query=' + $('#query').val();
});
```

Comment: If i wanted to add an id, where exactly will i do it? In the form or the dive

Comment: @Renuz Updated it too. Check.

Comment: @Renuz You need to put `id` both in the button and the `input`

Comment: <input ng-model = "query"  id = "query" is on another page, product.html. Is that going to change how i link it?

Comment: So we are linking location.href to another html page correct? So the page that conatins <input ng-model = "query" id = "query"/> is on another page. product.html

Comment: How is it to link to the other page? right now Im getting an error. Im placing the script below the first forum

Comment: file:///home/destiny/Desktop/ecomSite/search?query=undefined

Comment: Yes but currently im running it on local to test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97794/discussion-between-renuz-and-praveen-kumar).